# Remove ChildAction from OutPutCache in MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, outputcache, donut-caching

I'm developing a website with MVC 5.2.3, it has a top menu bar in `_Layout.cshtml` that contains logged in user information. Like user's FullName, so it shouldn't be cache.
For exclude this menu from OutPutCache, I created a child action for it.

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public PartialViewResult TopMenu()
{
    return PartialView("~/Views/Partials/TopMenuPartial.cshtml");
}
```

After that, I installed `MvcDonutCaching` nuget package and use it in `_Layout.cshtml` as the following:

```
@Html.Action("TopMenu", "Home", true)
```

But, it doesn't work, and if someone login, it's FullName came in top menu bar for all clients.

How should I remove this child action from MVC `OutPutCache`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem,
I didn't use `DonutOutputCache` attribute for output cache on actions, I used `OutPutCache` instead.
I changed it to `DonutOutputCache`, and add the following setting in `Application_Start`

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
...
DevTrends.MvcDonutCaching.OutputCache.DefaultOptions = DevTrends.MvcDonutCaching.OutputCacheOptions.ReplaceDonutsInChildActions;
...
}
```

Now, my problem solved.